# Testing Firebase Classes in swift Xctest

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, xctest

I am putting together an app using firebase and I want to make sure that I can run tests on it.  There isn't a lot of documentation about it - so I wanted to see if I was doing it the right way - or if I was doing it completely wrong.

Some of the the things that don't feel right about this solution: 
1. I am running FirApp.configure each time I spin up a new test class - isn't there a way that this can be shared? eg similar to how AppDelegate operates on an app. Currently this seems to be conflicting so the tests aren't writing anything to the DB. 
2. I have to auth each time I do a new class - is this possible to be shared. (ie in a Pre-Setup setup file?)

```
import XCTest
import Firebase

@testable import BurgerRestaurant
class BurgerTests: XCTestCase {
    var sut:Burger!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        FIRApp.configure()
        self.sut = Constants.MockedObjects.testBurger


    }

    override func tearDown() {
        sut = nil
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testSave() {
        if TestSettings.useRealFBaseCalls {
            let testSave = self.expectation(description: "Saving Burger Object")
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: TestSettings.testFireBUser, password: TestSettings.testFireBPass, completion: { (user, error) in


                self.sut.save(completion: { 
                    testSave.fulfill()
                })

            })
        }
    self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 15, handler: nil)
    }
}
```

Ideas are welcome on how to get the testing working.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(My opinion is that) you really shouldn't be testing that Firebase does what it's supposed to, you should just be testing that *YOUR* code does what it's supposed to. Firebase should have its own tests. I would set up a mock for Firebase and provide that to your test cases and ensure that your code is making the calls it should be. There are a couple of Firebase test mocks avilable on GitHub. (I've not used Firebase, so I can't attest to how good these are or if they'll even fit your needs, just some that I was able to find quickly):

https://github.com/katowulf/mockfirebase

https://github.com/soumak77/firebase-mock

Comment: Agree with you Jordan - thanks for sharing it -. Am going to try out those and post a result here